# Use XIB from parent class in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently I have a newsfeed with custom UITableViewCells such as :

```
NewsCell.m
NewsCell.xib


NewsCell_Friends.m
NewsCell_Friends.xib
NewsCell_CheckinPhoto.m
NewsCell_CheckinPhoto.xib
```

[...]

NewsCell_Friends and NewsCell_Checkin inherit both from NewsCell (methods and elements such as titleLabel, dateLabel that are shared by all subclasses)

At the moment, I have never used NewsCell class itself and only subclasses as each kind of news has a very distinct layout (Xib).

Let's say now that, I would like to have a light implementation in terms of UI of my newsfeed where all cells have the same appearance, same height, same content : the titleLabel and the dateLabel.
(Such as a notification feed in fact).

What I would like to do is to reuse NewsCell.xib as a standalone for every type of news, e.g. below :

```
NewsCell_CheckinPhoto *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckinPhoto"];
    if (!cell){
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (NewsCell_CheckinPhoto *)c.view;
        cell.parent = self;
    }
    [cell configureCell:indexPath withNews:news];
    return  cell;
```

in the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** delegate methods.

Notice that I use the NewsCell xib and not the NewsCell_CheckinPhoto xib in this controller.

But it is not working :the nib file is well loaded and the content of the NewsCell.xib well displayed in the cell, BUT the configuration of the labels (e.g, titleLabel.text = @"Robert took a photo") within the NewsCell_CheckinPhoto class is neither working nor even called.

It works only if I specify class type *NewsCell_CheckinPhoto* in the NewsCell.xib file , but that would not allow me to reuse NewsCell.xib for rendering each subclasses of NewsCell with a sample and unique representation.

Comment: Bumping this thread. Did not find a solution at this time :(

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you correct you want to load a cell from a XIB.
You should not do it with

`UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsCell" bundle:nil];`
but put only the cell in the XIB and then load it with

`UITableViewCell *cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell"][0];`

or similar (please check docs).

Also keep in mind when you load something like a table view cell from a XIB, it is initialised with `initWithCoder:`, not `init`, or `initWithFrame:`. This might be the reason, why your outlets are not intialised.

Comment: Yep, thanks you for pointing that. 

But using the more usual way :
            `cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell" owner:self options:nil][0];` does not change something.

 Also, I set the content of the IBOutlet not in the init methods, but in the configureCell:withNews method.